# Handling Null values in query

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, null

I want to avoid subscribers with the UtmSource value: 'https://survey.wilke.dk/' to enter my welcome flow. First thing I did was search for that exact value and found 6 subscribers with this UtmSource value.

But if try not adding them to my data extension by adding this line to my query:

```
UtmSource__c != 'https://survey.wilke.dk/'
```

the result is that everybody with the UtmSource value: 'https://survey.wilke.dk/' AND everybody with NULL in the UtmSource field are not added to the welcome flow data extension.

What should I do differently to only exclude those with the UtmSource value: 'https://survey.wilke.dk/'

Full code:

```
SELECT Id as [Account:Id]
, Country__c as [Account:Country__c]
, Language__c as [Account:Language__c]
, FirstName as [Account:FirstName]
, LastName as [Account:LastName]
, Gender__pc as [Account:Gender__pc]
, PersonContactId as [Account:PersonContact:Id]
, PersonEmail as [Account:PersonContact:Email]
, Consent_Date_First__c as [Account:Consent_Date_First__c]
, Consent_Source_First__c as [Account:Consent_Source_First__c]
, Consent_Method_First__c as [Account:Consent_Method_First__c]
, Consent_Type__c as [Account:Consent_Type__c]
, UtmCampaign__c as [Account:UtmCampaign__c]
, UtmContent__c as [Account:UtmContent__c]
, UtmMedium__c as [Account:UtmMedium__c]
, UtmSource__c as [Account:UtmSource__c]
, UtmTerm__c as [Account:UtmTerm__c]
FROM Account_Salesforce
WHERE PersonEmail IS NOT NULL
AND Consent_Source_First__c != 'Batch Upload'
AND UtmSource__c != 'https://survey.wilke.dk/'
AND Consent_Status__c = 'Confirmed'
AND Channel_Email__c = 1
AND Pref_Newsletter__c = 1
AND Consent_Date_First__c > dateadd(day,-3,getdate())
```

Thank you

Comment: The issue is you are running into sql 3 value logic. Here is an article that will give more info on it: https://gortonington.com/sfmc-sql-and-the-three-valued-logic-involving-null/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, weekend has passed  and reworking the issue with fresh eyes, I was able to actually provide a simple solution.

On my own way understanding, I created this DemoSource data extension, allowing for NULL in the UtmSource field:

[image]

I then approached this data extension with this query:

```
SELECT SubscriberKey
, EmailAddress
, UtmSource
FROM DemoSource
WHERE UtmSource LIKE '%wilke%'
```

and I could easily recognize those subscribers that had the answered our Wilke survey.
This is the result of the first query:

[image]

Trying to exclude these when populating my target data extension without handling NULL led me to the wrong result though.

2nd query

```
SELECT SubscriberKey
, EmailAddress
, UtmSource
FROM DemoSource
WHERE UtmSource NOT LIKE '%wilke%'
```

2nd result

[image]

So, I realized I needed to combine allowing for NULL values when excluding those Wilke survey participants, like this:

```
SELECT SubscriberKey
, EmailAddress
, UtmSource
FROM DemoSource
WHERE (UtmSource IS NULL OR UtmSource NOT LIKE '%wilke%')
```

Leading this the result I wanted:

[image]

With this knowledge fresh in mind I added this line to my initial query:

```
AND (UtmSource__c IS NULL OR UtmSource__c NOT LIKE '%wilke%')
```

and finally I was able to not only exclude those survey participants from having the welcome flow, which would be of little value to them, but also happy because I realized I'd learned a simple, valuable lesson of handling NULL values in queries :)

Thanks to @jonas-lambery and @gortonington for opening my eyes and leading my down the right path.

Answer (score 2):

You could add those two lines:

```
AND UtmSource__c != ''
AND UtmSource__c IS NOT NULL
```